Invalid name for HTML Custom Elements error
I'm trying to make an HTML page which has the list of all the anime I watched and am about to watch. So, I was trying to make an <anime> tag for convenience purpose. It has name and time attributes. Here is the code for the custom elements:
Expected output: □ □ One Piece (15 Days)
Running this is giving the following error: Uncaught DOMException: CustomElementRegistry.define: 'anime' is not a valid custom element name
I've researched about valid custom element names, and this satisfies all those rules:

any letter/symbol except capital letters
start with lower case letter
hyphens for spaces to separate words (here the name is only one word though)



class Anime extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    let name = this.getAttribute("name");
    let time = this.getAttribute("time");

    let children = [document.createElement("input"), document.createElement("input"), document.createElement("span"), document.createElement("b")];
    children[0].type = "checkbox";
    children[1].type = "checkbox";
    children[3].innerHTML = name;
    children[2].append(children[3]);
    children[2].append(` ${time}`);
    this.append(children[0], children[1], children[2]);
  }
}

customElements.define("anime", Anime);
<anime name="One Piece" time="15 Days">




Oh, and both the checkboxes aren't differentiated between here. But after this, I'm going to give them different class names

Name of the custom element must start with a lowercase letter, contain a hyphen, and satisfy certain other rules listed in the in the specification's definition of a valid name
Syntax

[a-z]* '-' [a-z]*

customElements.define("anime-element", Anime);  //✅

In HTML
<anime-element name="One Piece" time="15 Days"></anime-element>


Ohhh, so it must have a hyphen. Thanks

Must start with [a-z] must contain at least one hypen, may contain Emoji


Custom Element names must contain at least one - (hyphen) so it never will conflict with any new HTML tags the WHATWG will add in the future.
Fun fact: the name may contain Emoji

You can't do DOM operations in the constructor(). As there might not be  DOM.(eg when elements are defined before DOM is parsed)
Easily tested by executing a document.createElement("a-element") in the DEV console.  (note: many "guru" developers get this wrong too, because they use the not required defer/async on their <script> calls without understanding what it does)
Long read: My DEV.to blog on the connectedCallback

Do DOM operations in the connectedCallback
That is the signal the element appeared in the DOM

extend HTMLDIVElement (or any existing Element) is called a Customized Built-In Element and will never be supported in the (Apple) Safari Browser.
Stick to Autonomous Elements extend HTMLElement unless you only deliver to Chromium and FireFox.
My StackOverflow post on this

An "empty" constructor


  constructor() {  
    super()
  }

is pointless, as a class by default "super" calls its parent (in this case the constructor in HTMLElement)

Use a helper function createElement so props and Eventlisteners can easily be set
and your code doesn't look like a dropped spaghetti dish.

Custom Elements (aka Web Components) must be closed with a closing tag
<a-element></a-element>

the defining class can be an anonymous class as 2nd parameter inside the define function.
You rarely need a Named class.


HTH


const createElement = (t,p={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(t),p);

customElements.define("a-element-", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let name = this.getAttribute("name") || "no name attribute";
    let time = this.getAttribute("time") || "no time attribute";
    this.append(
      this.inp1 = createElement("input", {
        type   : "checkbox",
        id     : "first",
        onclick: (evt) => { // no need for addEventListener
          alert("clicked input: " + this.inp1.id);
        }
      }),
      createElement("input",{
        type: "checkbox",
        className: "cl1 cl2"  // sets the whole class String
      }),
      createElement("span",{
        innerHTML: `${name} <b>${time}</b>`
      })
    );
  }
});
<style>
  input { zoom:2 }
  .cl2  { zoom:3 }
</style>

<a-element- name="One Piece" time="15 Days"></a-element->



Or let ChatGPT write you a Web Component

